# apache derby disconnect exception with java ee and netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

i'm a newbie with Java EE and i'm following some guides, now i was trying to create a more complex Enterprise Project based on this NetBeans tutorial:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-entapp-ejb.html

When deploying, i get the following error on the server log:

"Connection could not be allocated because: Connection have been refused because the database "sample" haven't been found".

When creating a new Entity class, following the instructions, i have found this sentence "For the Data Source, choose a data source (for example, select jdbc/sample if you want to use JavaDB)."

Can you help me to solve my doubts?

```
Grave:   <ejb-class> value [com.newsapp.NewMessage] in ejb-jar.xml for ejb-name [NewMessage] does not match class name[ejb.NewMessage] for corresponding component-defining annotation.
 symbol: TYPE location: class ejb.NewMessage

Grave:   Annotations processing failed for file:/C:/Users/donpelajo/Documents/NetBeansProjects/NewsApp/dist/gfdeploy/NewsApp/NewsApp-ejb_jar/
Informazioni:   visiting unvisited references
Informazioni:   visiting unvisited references
Informazioni:   visiting unvisited references
Informazioni:   visiting unvisited references
Informazioni:   com.newsapp.NewsEntity actually got transformed
Informazioni:   ejb.NewsEntities actually got transformed
Informazioni:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
Informazioni:   file:/C:/Users/donpelajo/Documents/NetBeansProjects/NewsApp/dist/gfdeploy/NewsApp/NewsApp-ejb_jar/_NewsApp-ejbPU login successful
Informazioni:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://MISTER:8686/jndi/rmi://MISTER:8686/jmxrmi
Informazioni:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [3700]
Informazioni:   addresslist.setjmsservice.provider
Informazioni:   jms.connection.url
Informazioni:   MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter: Version:  5.1  (Build 9-b) Compile:  July 29 2014 1229
Informazioni:   MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter starting: broker is EMBEDDED, connection mode is Direct
Informazioni:   MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter Started:EMBEDDED
Avvertenza:   RAR8501: Exception during endpoint activation for ra [ jmsra ], activationSpecClass [ com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ActivationSpec ] : javax.resource.ResourceException: MQRA:EC:Invalid destinationLookup jms/NewMessage configured in ActivationSpec of MDB for no JNDI name found
Grave:   MDB00017: [NewMessage]: Exception in creating message-driven bean container: [java.lang.Exception]
Grave:   java.lang.Exception
java.lang.Exception
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainerFactory.createContainer(MessageBeanContainerFactory.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: MQRA:EC:Invalid destinationLookup jms/NewMessage configured in ActivationSpec of MDB for no JNDI name found
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer.setDestinationType(EndpointConsumer.java:758)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer._init(EndpointConsumer.java:299)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer.<init>(EndpointConsumer.java:190)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapter.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:207)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jms/NewMessage' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: NewMessage not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.Util.jndiLookup(Util.java:333)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer.setDestinationType(EndpointConsumer.java:755)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: NewMessage not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    ... 55 more

Grave:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainerFactory.createContainer(MessageBeanContainerFactory.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: MQRA:EC:Invalid destinationLookup jms/NewMessage configured in ActivationSpec of MDB for no JNDI name found
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer.setDestinationType(EndpointConsumer.java:758)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer._init(EndpointConsumer.java:299)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer.<init>(EndpointConsumer.java:190)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapter.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:207)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jms/NewMessage' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: NewMessage not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.Util.jndiLookup(Util.java:333)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer.setDestinationType(EndpointConsumer.java:755)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: NewMessage not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    ... 55 more

Grave:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainerFactory.createContainer(MessageBeanContainerFactory.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: MQRA:EC:Invalid destinationLookup jms/NewMessage configured in ActivationSpec of MDB for no JNDI name found
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer.setDestinationType(EndpointConsumer.java:758)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer._init(EndpointConsumer.java:299)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer.<init>(EndpointConsumer.java:190)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapter.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:207)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jms/NewMessage' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: NewMessage not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.Util.jndiLookup(Util.java:333)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer.setDestinationType(EndpointConsumer.java:755)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: NewMessage not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    ... 55 more

Grave:   Exception while loading the app
Informazioni:   file:/C:/Users/donpelajo/Documents/NetBeansProjects/NewsApp/dist/gfdeploy/NewsApp/NewsApp-ejb_jar/_NewsApp-ejbPU logout successful
Grave:   Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
java.lang.Exception
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainerFactory.createContainer(MessageBeanContainerFactory.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: MQRA:EC:Invalid destinationLookup jms/NewMessage configured in ActivationSpec of MDB for no JNDI name found
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer.setDestinationType(EndpointConsumer.java:758)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer._init(EndpointConsumer.java:299)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer.<init>(EndpointConsumer.java:190)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapter.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:207)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jms/NewMessage' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: NewMessage not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.Util.jndiLookup(Util.java:333)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.EndpointConsumer.setDestinationType(EndpointConsumer.java:755)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: NewMessage not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    ... 55 more
```

Comment: Please update the question with the complete exception stacktrace. Did you make sure the Derby server is started?

Comment: Solved, i didn't understand that the problem was in the admin console...the jdbc/sample simply have a bug and the jdbc/__default allows the connection, but when you create a jms message it's better to create it from the GlassFish admin panel :) This could be helpful for those who are beginning to study EJBs

Comment: Please,i'm testing the same tuto and i have the same error ! i have to change jdbc/sample par jdbc/__default  in the file persitence.xml ? Thanks a lot for help @dabadee